# zsh parameter substitution

Tags: shell-script, zsh, function

[This page](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Intro/intro_5.html#SEC5) has a demo function as follows:

```
~inews> namedir () { $1=$PWD ;  : ~$1 }
```

But when I try it on my machine, it produces the following error:

```
namedir: no such file or directory: test=/home/user
```

It looks like the function tries to `cd` into `$1=$PWD`. Just in case, I also tried the same function without `autocd` enabled. Do you have any idea for the error?

Answer (score 2):

I've no idea how that's supposed to work. Assignments don't take the `$` sign on the left, so `$1=$PWD` would not be recognized as an assignment, and would instead just expand both variables and then try to run that as a command. If you used `namedir test` in `/home/user`, it would expand to `test=/home/user` and give that error.

The [manual](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Dynamic-named-directories) mentions named directories can be set with `hash -d name=/dir`, so something like this should work:

```
namedir() { hash -d "$1=$PWD"; }
```

The [table of contents](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Intro/intro_toc.html) for that intro says "This document was generated on 30 November 1995 using the texi2html translator version 1.44.", so I wonder if it's completely up to date, and if named directories have worked differently in the past. (Even so, the page says "When you reference a directory in the form ~inews...", but I can't see how that would work either.)

Comment: Yeah. I am inclined to think of this as a forgotten to-do-list of some sort and move on.

Comment: I suspect they meant `namedir() { eval $1=\$PWD ; : ~$1 }`: assign the contents of `$PWD` to the variable whose name is in `$1`.